# Windows 10 pro bitlocker is not working

Tags: windows-10, encryption, bitlocker

My Dell laptop has Windows 10 professional edition and previously it has a working bitlocker program. But now can't open bitlocker using start menu or control panel.When I search bitlocker from start menu, "Manage bitlocker" label appears.But when I try to click it, nothing happens. Also control panel is not showing bitlocker program. By the way I have a bitlocker protected external hard disk. I can open that hard disk by giving the password when the popup menu comes up. But I want to turn off the bitlocker and still I can't do it.

[image: This image shows how my start menu shows bitlocker]

Comment: "but now can't open bitlocker" - What happens when you do, edit your question, and provide specific details.  What build of Windows 10?